# Conditional version of martingale difference concentration inequality

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities

Let $M_n$ be a $\mathscr{F}_n=\sigma(\eta_m,\theta_m, m\leq n)$ measurable martingale difference sequence. Then is it possible to find a exponential tail bound for the following
$$P(|M_{n+1}| > u|\mathscr{F}_n)$$

where $M_{n+1} = f(\theta_n, \eta_{n+1})-E[f(\theta_n, \eta_{n+1})|\mathcal{F}_n]$ and $\eta_n$ i.i,d

Comment: What do you mean by an exponential concentration inequality? And what is $\theta_n$?

Comment: @losif: I have made it elaborate.